# У кого-то еще пропадали иконки с рабочего стола?

Tags: windows

После обновления на 21h1 На рабочем столе пропали иконки ярлыков. Остались лишь из названия. Так же пропало все содержимое control center. Помогите исправить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как исправить - например откатить систему до точки восстановления до обновления.

Answer (score 2):

Переустановка/откатить с помощью точки восстановления

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте очистить кэш иконок рабочего стола.
Кеш иконок хранится в файле C:\Users[Пользователь]\AppData\Local\IconCache.db. Его необходимо удалить и перезагрузить систему. Однако есть способ, позволяющий обойтись без перезагрузки:
Необходимо закрыть процесс Explorer.exe, отвечающий за оболочку рабочего стола: открываем меню Пуск, зажимаем Ctrl+Shift, нажимаем правой клавишей мыши в свободном пространстве меню Пуск, в появившемся контекстном меню выбираем «Выход из Проводника».
Запускаем Диспетчер задач нажатием Ctrl+Shift+Esc.
Выбираем Файл -> Новая задача -> cmd.exe -> Ok.
Поочередно вводим команды в появившееся окно:

```
cd /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local
```

```
del IconCache.db
```

```
explorer.exe
```